# using javascript in the onclick attribute

Tags: javascript, html, forms, onclick

i posted a question earlier and got it answerd thanks to the wonderful people here, but as my luck goes, its never that easy. i have a code that switches back and forth between pictures onclick, however, the first time you click, the picture doesnt switch, but the checkbox is checked. at the very least a reasoning would be superb :)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function func()
{
    var img1= document.getElementById("img1");

    if(img1.name == "on")
    {
        img1.src = "images/" + "img1a.jpg";
        img1.name = "off";
    }
    else
    {
        img1.src = "images/" + "img1.jpg";
        img1.name = "on";
    }
}
</script>



</head>

<body>
<form>
<p align="center">
<input type="checkbox" name="interest1" id="interest1" value="x">
<input type="checkbox" name="interest2" id="interest2" value="x">
<input type="checkbox" name="interest3" id="interest3" value="x"></p>   
<p align="center">
<label for="interest1" id="label-interest1"><img src="images/img1.jpg" width="781" height="800" onclick="func()" id="img1" /></label>
<label for="interest2" id="label-interest2"><img src="/images/img2.jpg" width="781" height="800" /></label>
<label for="interest3" id="label-interest3"><img src="/images/img3.jpg" width="781" height="800" /></label></P><!-- code making checkbox be an image-->
</form>
```

Comment: The first time `func()` is ran, no `name` property exists, so the `else` block is executed, which sets the `src` to what it's already set to. Either swap which image is assigned in each block, or add `name="on"` by default...

Comment: I read this question and answers and decided you need a little boost. http://jsfiddle.net/4G9f8/3/ (edits because i'm stupid) check this out. Google each function if you need to (use MDN, not w3schools). Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are lacking the first state of "on". Try adding this to your markup

```
 <img src="images/img1.jpg" width="781" height="800" onclick="func()" name="on" id="img1" />
```

Conversely, you could handle this in javascript in your conditional statement like this:

```
if(img1.name === undefined || img1.name == "on")
```

which would handle the first state where a name attribute was not present.

Answer (score 1):

Since your `img` element doesn't have a `name` attribute, it doesn't match "on" condition the first time it is clicked. You could add a name attribute (which would work, but make the html invalid), but a better solution might be to get the value from the checkbox you are associating it with. Something like this:

```
var checkboxid = img1.parentNode.getAttribute("for");
document.getElementById(checkboxid).checked
```

This way, you can be *sure* it is kept in sync with the checkbox.

Comment: I know that this is super late, but how would i get this to work in my JS? i can't seem to figure it out